# non linear Fit with a parametric value

Tags: fitting

i have 4 sets of data of **JCS** as a function of **T** at 4 different **B** values
the equation is
**JCS** = JCST*Exp[-(**B**/*BSC*)];

JCST = *JCS0**(1 - **T**/78.4)^alpha2;

BSC = BSC0*Exp[-(**T**/*TSC*)];

where JCS0 BSC and TCS have to be the same for all the dataset while B changes for each data but they are known.
i use to do a fit whit a single data set setting B every fit, but I get different best values for JCS0 BSC and TCS.
how can I perform a single Fit of **JCS** vs **T** with all 4 sets of data including the fact that B is not a fitting parameter but is a know value?

thanx
modified to add the code I'm using actually

````
JCS = JCST*Exp[-(B/BSC)];
JCST = JCS0*(1 - T/78.4)^alpha2;
BSC = BSC0*Exp[-(T/TSC)];
JCS2 = JCS /. {B -> 1}

fit3T = NonlinearModelFit[
   a1T, {JCS2, alpha2 > 0,  BSC0 > 0, 
    TSC > 0}, {{TSC, 8}, {JCS0, 0.5}, {BSC0, 90}, {alpha2, 0.8}},
    T];
fit3Ta = fit3T["BestFitParameters"]

Show[ListLogPlot[a1T, PlotRange -> {{0, 90}, {0.0001, 2}}, 
  PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.02]], 
 LogPlot[JCS2 /. fit3Ta, {T, 0, 90}, PlotRange -> {0.0001, 2}]]
```
````

Comment: Please make use of code blocks and ensure that the question is readable / the code is copyable.

Comment: @Szabolcs what do you mean with code blocks?

Comment: MAybe the following may help: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5362/finding-a-fit-to-a-multi-dimensioned-function

Comment: Check my resource function [MultiNonlinearModelFit](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/MultiNonlinearModelFit)

Comment: @SjoerdSmit 's `MultiNonlinearModelFit` is the way to go but it does assume (and please correct me if I'm wrong) that the error variances are identical among the individual models.  If the response variables are in different units, then that assumption of a common error variance, it unlikely to be true.

Comment: @JimB You can apply different weights to the different datasets to compensate I guess. Or you rescale. For exponential models you have to reconsider the standard error assumptions anyway, because they range over many orders of magnitude.

Comment: @SjoerdSmit Agreed - if one "knows" the weights as opposed to estimating the weights.  And you point about exponential models is great:  one needs to look at the residuals to see if the error function part of the model is appropriate.

Comment: thanx all guy
i solved using LogLikelihood function and minimizing the parameter with all data sets