# Fitting real and imaginary parts of a function

Tags: plotting, fitting, complex

I have an analytic form of a function

```
G[w_] = -I*z0*w/(1 + I*z0*w*a)
```

I know this function can be obtained (up to some overall normalization) from solving a differential equation numerically for small `w`

```
g[z_] := 1 + 3 (z/z0)^4 - 4 (z/z0)^3

DE = x''[z] + D[g[z]/z^2, z]/(g[z]/z^2) x'[z] + (w^2)/(g[z])^2 x[z] == 0;

pfun = Block[{z0 = 0.1, eps = 10^-2, zb = 10^-2}, 
   ParametricNDSolveValue[{DE, x'[z0 - eps] == I (z0^2 w)/(6 eps^2)  x[z0 - eps], x[zb] == 1},
    - (x'[zb]/zb^2),
    {z, zb, z0 - eps},
    {w}
   ]
  ]
```

But `G[w]` and `pfun[w]` are two complex functions. To fit them (up to over all normalization) I need to fit the real and the imaginary parts separately. To fix the overall normalization once and for all I compute the ratio for very small `w`(the normalization doesn't depend on `a` for very small `w` as one can see from the expression of `G[w]`).

```
test[a_] := Evaluate[Im[pfun[0.0005]]/Im[-((I w *0.1 )/(1 + I w *0.1* a)) //. w -> 0.0005]]
```

`test[a]` is approximately `1080` for large range of `a`.

Now if I try to match the real and imaginary parts independently the value of `a` comes out to be quite different in two fits!

```
list1 = Table[{w, Evaluate[Re[pfun[w]]]}, {w, -2, 2, 0.1}]

aValue1 = FindFit[list1, Re[-1080.13 (I*w*0.1 )/(1 + I*w*0.1*a)], a, w]
```

This gives `a=9.49`

```
L1 = ListPlot[list1];
Show[Plot[Re[ -1080.13 (I w*0.1 )/(1 + I w*0.1*a)] //. aValue1, {w, -5, 5}], L1]]
```

[image: Real parts of <code>G[w]</code>]

Where as fitting the imaginary part in similar fashion I get a different value of `a`.

```
list2 = Table[{w, Evaluate[Im[pfun[w]]]}, {w, -2, 2, 0.2}];
aValue2 = FindFit[list2, Im[-1080.13 (I*w*0.1)/(1 + I*w*0.1*a)], a, w]
```

This gives `a=1.35`

```
L2 = ListPlot[list2];
Show[Plot[Im[ -1080.13 (I w*0.1 )/(1 + I w*0.1*a)] //. aValue2, {w, -20, 20}], L2]]
```

[image: Imaginary parts of <code>G[w]</code>]

My question is what should be the best fit value of `a`?

Comment: I edited your code to fix the code-formatting a bit (use four-space indentations for non-inline code blocks instead of the back-ticks), but there were some funny formatting symbols that showed up, so I'm not entirely sure I didn't delete something important. Please check to make sure it looks correct!

Comment: @march Sorry about the format and thanks for editing! :) I'll check..

Comment: See [this post](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/866/simultaneously-fitting-multiple-datasets) and others it links to for simultaneous fitting (overlapping or same parameters, different data sets).

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to fit the imaginary and real parts of your data separately; indeed, fitting them together should give you more accurate results.

`FindFit` will happily deal with complex-valued functions of real paramters. You just need to give it **assumptions on the values of those parameters**, and to select an **appropriate norm function** to use in the minimization process.

For instance, with your definitions:

```
g[z_] := 1 + 3 (z/z0)^4 - 4 (z/z0)^3
DE = x''[z] + D[g[z]/z^2, z]/(g[z]/z^2) x'[z]8 + (w^2)/(g[z])^2 x[z] == 0;
pfun = Block[
   {z0 = 0.1, eps = 10^-2, zb = 10^-2},
   ParametricNDSolveValue[
     {DE, x'[z0 - eps] == I (z0^2 w)/(6 eps^2) x[z0 - eps], x[zb] == 1},
     -(x'[zb]/zb^2),
     {z, zb, z0 - eps}, w
   ]
 ];
```

we can calculate a list of complex values to fit, for small $w$ values:

```
list = Table[{w, pfun[w]}, {w, -1, 1, 0.05}];
```

The parametric function throws a few warnings on boundary conditions so you should check for the consistency of your model, but nonetheless it returns a list of values we can work with.

We then set up a model of the form you specified above (`G[w]`) in your original code:

```
model = -const I z0 w/(1 + I z0 w a) /. z0 -> 1/10;
```

Rather than using an estimated multiplicative constant in the model, we include one in the model to determine through fitting (`const`); I also included the value of $z_0=0.1$, so the free parameters are `const` and `a`.

We then set up the fitting function. In addition to a standard fitting procedure, we add the following:

1. specify that `a` and `const` are real-valued;
2. select the 1-norm (`Norm[#, 1]&` which corresponds to `Total[Abs[#]]&`) as the norm function;
3. give reasonable starting values for the parameters.

This results in:

```
fit = FindFit[
   list,
   {model, {a, const} ∈ Reals},
   {{a, 10}, {const, 1000}}, w, NormFunction -> (Norm[#, 1] &)
 ]

(* Out: {a -> 8.92677, const -> 1529.84} *)
```

Here is a plot of the real and imaginary parts of `list`, together with the corresponding fitted functions:

```
Show[
 ListPlot[Transpose@ReIm[list[[All, 2]]], DataRange -> MinMax@list[[All, 1]]],
 Plot[Evaluate@ReIm[model /. fit], Evaluate@Flatten@{w, MinMax@list[[All, 1]]}]
]
```

[image: results of fit]